# jquery variable doesn't change on update

Tags: javascript, jquery

This my problem's semplification. I want to append some text after an input field (on update of the same field), only when the value of a select element is IT.

That's the fields:

```
<select id="billing_country">
    <option value="FR">FR</option>
    <option value="IT">IT</option>
</select>

<input type="text" id="woocommerce_cf_piva">
```

this is the script:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

var $country_select = jQuery('#billing_country');

// When country change
$country_select.change(function () {

    var $country = jQuery('#billing_country option:selected');

    $country.each(function() {

        FieldCheck(jQuery(this).val());
    })
});

function FieldCheck($country) {

    var $element = jQuery('#woocommerce_cf_piva');

    if ($country == 'IT') {

        $element.change(function () {

            $element.after($country);
        });
    }
}
});
```

You can [see this also on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zuuuLwd3/#&togetherjs=VrhEaiCaAh)

Why it append country name also if i select FR?

Comment: You are adding a NEW event handler when you do a FieldCheck and have IT set; Then if you change the value, the event handler STAYS; even if the value changes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a span and put the text in there so on subsequent change you can fix it:

```
<select id="billing_country">
  <option value="FR">FR</option>
  <option value="IT">IT</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="woocommerce_cf_piva" /><span id="afterit"></span>
```

Note that this is still pretty verbose:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var $country_select = jQuery('#billing_country');
  var $element = jQuery('#woocommerce_cf_piva');

  // When country change
  $country_select.on('change', function() {
    var $country = jQuery(this).find('option:selected')[0].value;
    var d = ($country == 'IT') ? $country : "";
    $element.data('selectedcountry', d);
  });

  $element.on('change', function() {
    var ct = $(this).data('selectedcountry');
    //as you have it: $(this).after(ct);// append
    // put it in the span to remove/blank out on subsequent changes
    $('#afterit').text(ct);
  });
});
```

Here is the total less-verbose version:

```
$('#woocommerce_cf_piva').on('change', function() {
    var v = $('#billing_country').find('option:selected')[0].value;
    $('#afterit').text((v == 'IT') ? v : "");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to understand what you're trying to do with your code.

You want the text input to change its value only if the select box has "IT" selected?

Why are you setting a `change` handler on the text input?

Why iterate through a select box's options if it's a single select? Just set the text input with the selected option's value, e.g.,

```
$(function() {
  var $billingCountry = $('#billing_country');

  $billingCountry.change(function() {
    var $country = $('#billing_country option:selected');
    fieldCheck($country.val());
  });

  function fieldCheck(country) {
    var $element = $('#woocommerce_cf_piva');
    if ($country !== 'IT') {
      return;
    }

    $element.val(country);
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/davelnewton/w5deffvk/

*Edits*

- Naming conventions changed to reflect typical JS

  - Non-constructor function names start with lower-case
  - Non-JQ element vars don't get a leading `$`
- Country value used as guard clause rather than nesting logic

  - This code is trivial, but nesting can make things harder to reason about

Comment: Thank you for answering, Dave!

The code you provide is more readable.
I want that when I change the text in the input field, jQuery append to the  input field a word (in this case IT)

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems:

1. `input` tag does not have `onchange` event; you should use `onkeydown` instead;
2. you should assign events before `if` conditions.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the problem correctly, you want to update input field with the value entered only when drop down selection is "IT". If that is the case, you need to watch input field event and invoke FieldCheck function from with in input field events.